# Need dataset for bank transaction

Tags: machine-learning, dataset

I want to make graph using bank transaction dataset between credit vs debit. Amount debited and credited but not getting proper dataset! 
Can anyone provide me dataset for the same?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Recently google have launched there own dataset platform and named it **[Google Dataset Search](https://toolbox.google.com/datasetsearch)**. You can search for the dataset you need. Having a large collection of dataset, I think you may get one that meets up your requirements.

Here I have got one for you. Hope it will help you.
https://toolbox.google.com/datasetsearch/search?query=Bank%20transactions&docid=sv20cU0dOX3wrVUWAAAAAA%3D%3D